# Unable to start Lightworks on Ubuntu 15.04 produces (app goes to blank screen)

Tags: software-installation, video-editor, lightworks

I wanted to try a video editor for Ubuntu and so I installed [Lightworks](http://www.lwks.com/).

Installation went fine, either by manually downloading the .deb from Lightworks website or by terminal.

However, in either case when I launch the application, it opens but all it shows is a blank/gradient gray screen. That's it.

I'm not sure what's the problem. Console didn't throw any error when starting the application from there. It just opens this window with gray gradients (I suppose that'd eventually be a partially rendered welcome screen from Lightworks?) and that's it. I can quit the application from launcher or ALT F4 without error.

My system is an i3, has 8 GB ram, runs on a SSD, has an Intel Graphics 3000 integrated gpu.

What could I do?

Comment: Start the application in a terminal, edit your question and post the output.

Comment: I did. Application starts, no strange output from terminal. But the application has a blank content, as I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

ok in case someone has the same problem

1. try restarting Ubuntu

if still doesn't change:

2. try the next beta version (I installed 12.5.A and solved the issue)